# Overview of/on/to...?

Tags: prepositions

What is the better alternative in a formal context?

> In this talk, a brief overview [of/on/to/OTHER] this topic is given.

I would use *'on'*, but I've seen that *'of'* seems to be the most used option. I actually do not know whether *'on'* or *'to'* are valid options in this expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["An overview **of** this topic" is so much more common than any other usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20overview%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Can%20overview%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20overview%20in%3B%2Cc0) that it's the only one that really makes sense.  It sounds the most natural to this native speaker too.  "An overview **on** this topic" sounds possible, whereas "an overview **to** this topic" just sounds completely wrong.